# Django DRF - ListCreateAPIView POST Failing with depth=2

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ListCreateAPIView`for showing a list of contacts, as well as for creating new contacts which uses this serializer:

```
class ContactPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = Contact
     exclude = ('id',)
```

For `POST`ing new records, I have to specifically exclude `id` so that DRF doesn't complain about a null `id`. But, for listing records with this serializer, the serializer doesn't return the objects in `ForeignKey` fields. To get these objects, I add `depth = 2`. So now the serializer looks like this:

```
class ContactPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = Contact
     exclude = ('id',)
     depth = 2
```

However, now, with `depth = 2`, I can't do `POST`s anymore. It complains again of null id values.

Edit: I should add that the errors that come up with I have `depth=2` are specific to the models of the Foreign Key objects, not the new record I'm creating.

What am I missing here?

Comment: is your `id` field an auto increment primary key? if so, no need to exclude `id` in your serializer. when you post data without `id` field, DRF will not complain for that, and a new id will be generated for you.

Comment: @Enix You're right, but that doesn't address the problem. I'll post answer to explain my solution

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem is that when the serializer has `depth=2` that part is not writeable. That's why it was failing. The other thing is that I didn't want to change my URL so that I only had `/contacts/` for both listing and for creating. To do that, I had to adjust my class for handling the responses.

Here's what I came up with:

## api.py

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Contact.objects.all()
  serializer_class = ContactSerializer

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # If we're creating (POST) then we switch serializers to the one that doesn't include depth = 2
    serializer = ContactCreateSerializer(data = request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      self.object = serializer.save()
      headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
      # Here we serialize the object with the proper depth = 2
      new_c = ContactSerializer(self.object)
      return Response(new_c.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers = headers)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## serializers

```
class ContactCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Contact
    exclude = ()

class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Contact
    exclude = ()
    depth = 2
```

Credit to this SO answer which helped me figure it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741062/717682

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the link that calls your view is /example/. 
If you want to POST data then you can call this like that: "/example/", 
If you want to GET data (with depth) you can call this like that: "/example/?depth="yes" 
You must have two serializers. One with the depth and one without it.

```
class ContactPOSTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        exclude = ('id',)

class ContactGETSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        exclude = ('id',)
        depth = 2
```

So then your view will be something like that:

```
class ExampleView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ContactPOSTSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        depth = self.request.query_params.get('depth', "")

        if (depth != "" and depth != "null"):
            serializer = ContactGETSerializer(context={'request': request})
            return Response(serializer.data)

        serializer = ContactPOSTSerializer(context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

It might not be the best solution but it worked for me :)